# ¿Cómo mostrar métodos sobrecargados en Swagger.UI con Swashbuckle .NET Framework 4.7?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, swagger, swagger-ui

Estoy trabajando con Swagger para la documentación de mi servicio API pero me encontré con un problema ya que en el controlador tengo dos métodos con el nombre Get por lo que Swagger solo toma el primero haciendo omisión del segundo método aunque este reciba otros parámetros.

```
[HttpGet]
public ModelResponse Get(int dato1, int dato2, int dato3, int dato4)

[HttpGet]
public ModelResponse Get(int dato1, int dato2, int dato3, int dato4, string Cadena1, string Cadena2)
```

Cada uno cuenta con su documentación pero solo me toma el primero

[image: Swagger.UI]

El controlador tiene 2 acciones Get y 1 Post entonces me debería listar 6 acciones porque repite las acciones por las dos maneras en que se puede consumir pero no me muestra la segunda acción Get a menos que le cambie el nombre a Get2 pero así afecto otras funcionalidades.

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: puedes cambiar el nombre de la llamada desde el verbo `HttpGet`

Answer (score 0):

Alguna vez pasé por un problema medianamente similar, el problema en cuestión era que tenía 2 verbos `GET` en el mismo controlador, así que me daba un error. lo que hice para cambiarlo fue lo siguiente. Suponiendo que tengo un controlador llamado `Usuarios`:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UsuariosController : ControllerBase
    {
    }
```

En la cuál, tenía 2 métodos `GET`:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<UsuarioDto> GetUserData()
{
    return Ok();
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<List<UsuarioDto>> GetUsuarios()
{
    return Ok();
}
```

el problema está, en que cuando quisiera llamar cualquiera de los dos métodos en el API, ambos se llamarían con la misma liga, que sería algo tipo:

> [www.midominio.com/api/Usuarios](http://www.midominio.com/api/Usuarios)

entonces, como en el api necesito ***Diferenciar las URL***, decidí ponerles nombres diferentes en el verbo `HttpGet`. quedó así:

```
[HttpGet("Usuario")]
public ActionResult<UsuarioDto> GetUserData()
{
    return Ok();
}

[HttpGet("Usuarios")]
public ActionResult<List<UsuarioDto>> GetUsuarios()
{
    return Ok();
}
```

Ahora, para llamar alguno de los dos métodos sería con 2 ***URL diferentes***:

> [www.midominio.com/api/Usuarios/Usuario](http://www.midominio.com/api/Usuarios/Usuario) (haría el métodoGetUserData())
> [www.midominio.com/api/Usuarios](http://www.midominio.com/api/Usuarios) (haría el GetUsuarios())

Espero que mi respuesta te sea de ayuda.

¡Saludos!

Comment: Es una buena solución pero de hacerlo de esa manera tendría que modificar la ruta para consumirlo y actualmente detecta si trae 4 parámetros toma el primer Get y si trae los 6 parámetros toma el Get número 2, todo esto por la sobrecarga del método, pero de no ser por eso tu respuesta es bastante útil se te agradece